# Android log and modify all HTTP requests

Tags: android, http, httpwebrequest

I am wondering what way I can log (sniff) all HTTP requests that are outgoing and incoming in whole Android and is it possible to modify them during that process or block ?

What libraries should I use ?

Comment: This sounds like it's going to be a malicious app!

Comment: Could be.  Could also be something attempting to provide protection from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need a rooted phone at least, which basically rules out distributing what you make on the market unfortunately..

With that in mind, take a look at [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/) :)