# Can we store all the http/https request of my phone using android app?

Tags: android, httpwebrequest

Can we store all the http/https request of my phone using android app?

Is there any way to store the traffic of my android app?

Comment: Possible duplicate... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922329/android-log-and-modify-all-http-requests?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922329/android-log-and-modify-all-http-requests?rq=1)

Comment: Ya but that solution is not for android app.
So please can you tell me how we can do that by using android.?

Comment: The answers from that question apply... *No* unless you root your phone.  If you are wondering about monitoring a specific app.. you can load it up in the emulator and monitor the emulator's requests using something like WireShark.  Android's security model will block you from doing this via any means with an unrooted phone.  Sorry